# Block game download from ads

Tags: applications, downloading, ads

How do I keep a senior citizen from downloading and installing every game from ads that pop up from games that are installed?  He has a few games he likes and ads pop up and he cannot be told about the X in the corner to keep from installing them.  His memory is a factor.  I need a block of some sort.  Every day that he plays, he has five more new games installed.  I need ad-free solitaire, mahjong, and pyramid solitaire, and he likes Bejeweled.  Does anyone get any ideas? And YES.. we have shown and told him not to.  It is forgotten.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to minimize the displayed ads using an app like [Blokada](https://blokada.org) (not available on Play Store). This app filters out ads and app trackers using filter lists that clock certain requests. This usually reduces the number of ads.

A second option would be to use the multi-user system on Android (if it is available on your device). Additionally to the primary user, you can create a second user who is not able to install any app.

The third option would be the [Google parental control system](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1075738) which is AFAIK able to block certain app installations. Just switch "parent" and "child" while reading ;)

Comment: thank you Robert.  It's worth giving anything a shot at this point.  The multi-user might be the answer, since I have to help them "FIX" the phone constantly.  He is happy with the 6 or 7 games he has and doesn't even realize he has downloaded around 3 to 4 every other day.